# Hiding a segment in a UISegmentedController

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am looking for a way to hide a segment in a UISegmentedController.  I can set the width to 0, but I get a strange bump in the border where the segment used to be.  Any ideas how to set isHidden?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well there are various way,

1) you can remove the segment at index based on your requirement or else you can set the **numberOfSegments** whenever you are creating the segment based on condition.

2) You can create the segment based on items

For example:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One"];

if(mychoice==2) {
  //add two more objects to itemArray
}else if (mychoice==3) {
  //add three more objects to itemArray
}

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
```

So you want to hide some particular index based on **some condition** in that situation you just change the items for itemArray;

3) you can set enable/disable the particular index rather than hiding;

Comment: Thanks for the post.  The difficulty I have is that this segment is in the middle, so everything get's bounced down, but my code still thinks the segment is there.  Really just want to hide the segment and have it sit silently in the background.

Comment: Okay then you can set the "opaque" properties to that segment control. opaque = 1 //i guess to hide, or may be 0; [should work];